# Not able to bind the Json data with Jquery Data table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have below json data which i am getting from api call.

```
 {   "data": [
        {
            "Id": "123",
            "name": "fgfnnn",
            "postCode": "123-456",
            "Address": "test",
            "street": "test3"
        },
        {
            "Id": "456",
            "name": "gggcgh",
            "postCode": null,
            "Address": null,
            "street": null
        }
    ]
   
}
```

I am trying to bind to the table tblHospital as below but getting error.

```
jQuery('#tblHospital').DataTable({
                    data: JSON.parse(res),
                     columns: [
                       { "data": "name" }
                {
                    "data": "address",
                           
                   "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                       return data.Address +  data.street + data.postCode;
                    }
                },
                       ]
                });
```

Can anyone pls help?
Error is like DataTables warning: table id=tblHospital - Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You have some configuration errors in the options for your Datatable.

First you're object is malformed. You're not closing or adding commas in the right place.

Second, you wrote `address` but your object has a capital `A` `Address`

Third, you can't use `data.Address` in your render function since it's only the value of the cell. You need to get the value of the row ( in your case it should be `full.Address` )

You can run the code below and you'll see it work.

```js
var data = [{
      "Id": "123",
      "name": "fgfnnn",
      "postCode": "123-456",
      "Address": "test",
      "street": "test3"
    },
    {
      "Id": "456",
      "name": "gggcgh",
      "postCode": null,
      "Address": null,
      "street": null
    }
  ];


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tblHospital').DataTable({
    data: data, //Here you'll have to keep JSON.parse(res). I had to change it since my values are in a variable above for this example to work.
    columns: [
    { "data": "name" }, 
    { "data": "Address", 
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
        return row.Address + ' ' + row.street + ' ' + row.postCode;
        }
    }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="tblHospital" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `ajax` instead of `data`. And make the API call in ajax.

```
jQuery('#tblHospital').DataTable({
    "ajax": //API call here,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        {
             "data": "address",             
             "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                           return data.Address +  data.street + data.postCode;
                       }
        },
    ]
});
```